# How to do some operations like groupby() and value_counts() in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, crosstab

Here is a pandas Dataframe defined as follow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'two'],
                   'C' : [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1]})
>>> df
     A      B  C
0  foo    one  0
1  bar    one  1
2  foo    two  0
3  bar  three  1
4  foo    two  1
5  bar    two  2
6  foo    one  0
7  foo  three  2
8  foo    two  1
```

I want to do two operations.

First, group the Dataframe by column `A` and `B`. Thus, 6 groups are obtained in this case. This operation is similar to groupby() function in pandas.

Then, for each group, do the count operation for column `C` since it can be three different values (0, 1 and 2) in this case. This operation is similar to value_counts() function in pandas.

Finally, I want a new Dataframe like this.

```
     A      B  C_value0  C_value1  C_value2
0  foo    one         2         0         0
1  foo    two         1         2         0
2  foo  three         0         0         1
3  bar    one         0         1         0
4  bar    two         0         0         1
5  bar  three         0         1         0
```

Could somebody tell me how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), then replace `NaN` to `0` by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), convert to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html), [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and last [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
print (df.groupby(['A','B', 'C'])['C'].size()
                                      .unstack()
                                      .fillna(0)
                                      .astype(int)
                                      .add_prefix('C_value')
                                      .reset_index()
                                      .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

     A      B  C_value0  C_value1  C_value2
0  bar    one         0         1         0
1  bar  three         0         1         0
2  bar    two         0         0         1
3  foo    one         2         0         0
4  foo  three         0         0         1
5  foo    two         1         2         0
```

Another solution with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
print (pd.crosstab([df.A, df.B], df.C)
         .add_prefix('C_value') 
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

     A      B  C_value0  C_value1  C_value2
0  bar    one         0         1         0
1  bar  three         0         1         0
2  bar    two         0         0         1
3  foo    one         2         0         0
4  foo  three         0         0         1
5  foo    two         1         2         0
```

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: When I run your code, an error came out. The error said "TypeError: must pass an index to rename". Then I delete ".rename_axis(None, axis=1)" and it can run successfully.

Comment: Yes, maybe you use lower version of pandas. instead `rename _axis` you can use `df = pd.crosstab([df.A, df.B], df.C).add_prefix('C_value').reset_index()` and 
    `df.columns.name = None` (or first solution also)

Comment: Your help was greatly appreciated.

Comment: Btw, I was very nicely surprised with your perfect sample, it is very not often in SO, (unfortunately) new users have very often no sample. Good luck and nice day!